# VBA Print #1 select range (for exporting from Excel to a file)?

Tags: excel, vba, export

I have a simple macro that exports desired cells to a txt-file. Can I instead of individually telling the macro what cells I want to export, choose a range of cells?

Here's the very simple code I have:

```
Sub TEST()
    Open "C:\text.txt" For Output As #1
        Print #1, Cells(1, 1) & Cells(1, 2)
        Close
End Sub
```

With that I can export Excel sheet cells A1, A2. But if I want to export wide range of cells, this method isn't too convenient. So is there a way I could, let's say easily export cells A1:A100?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see joseph4tw has already responded, but my answer is a little different and might give you another idea, so I'll put it here anyway.

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim c As Range, r As Range
    Dim output As String
    For Each r In Range("A1:C3").Rows
        For Each c In r.Cells
            output = output & c.Value & ","
        Next c
        output = output & vbNewLine
    Next r
    Open "H:\My Documents\text.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, output
    Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this solution up. I was about to change my answer, but I realized that this would be perfect for the OP :)

Comment: The output text file has a leading comma "," separator. How can we get rid of it via the same script?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25431598 (thanks to the author!). I'll edit my answer because I think this is undesirable behaviour for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `InputBox` and set the type to `8`, which will allow the user to click in Excel and select a range.

Here is an example:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Excel.Range, cell As Excel.Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = Application.InputBox("Select Range", "Select Range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Open "C:\text.txt" For Output As #1
    For Each cell In r
        Print #1, cell.Value
    Next
    Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to input the range in the macro itself? That's a nice solution, but in my case I'm exporting hundreds of txt-files with those kind of macros, so I'd have to choose the range too many times.

Comment: I'm just curious, why did you specify Excel.Range rather than just Range? I think this is eminently sensible, but wondering about your reasoning :)

Comment: @user2084296 you just need to assign the range to the `r` variable in @joseph4tw's example.

Comment: @mkingston, I read some time ago about how the code will actually compile/run faster if you fully qualify the objects and I just got used to it. The quote was: `If you declare variables and arguments with a generic Object data type, Visual Basic may have to resolve references to their properties and methods when it encounters them at run time, resulting in a significantly slower process.`

Comment: Ah right. Seems likely it would at least compile faster, thanks for that. The reason I'd thought it was sensible previously was because when you try to move your code (to Word especially, a Word.Range is quite different) you have to go through your code and change all your Range objects to Excel.Range objects anyway, easier to just have them fully defined to begin with.

Comment: @user2084296, it might actually be more efficient to copy the relevant range to a new worksheet and save that as a csv. Especially if you have a lot of these to do. Just a thought.

Comment: @mkingston I agree that it would be easier to move the code from one Office product to another. In general, I like to be very explicit when I write code (even to the point of `For i = 1 to 10 ... Next i` where you don't have to put `i`, just `Next`). I also find it easier to maintain later on.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the example by mkingston puts the comma first. This would cause everything to start in the second column of the .csv (first column would be blank). A little better would be to put the comma at the end of the statement. You could remove the last ',' with REPLACE() but it isn't necessary.

```
   Dim c As range, r As range
        Dim output As String
        For Each r In range(DataRange).Rows
            For Each c In r.Cells
                output = output & c.Value & ","
            Next c
            output = output & vbNewLine

        Next r
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all non-empty cells (contigouos) use this:

```
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
```

You can then export it in whatever way you fancy ;)